# How do I know which block is caching or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I want to find out which part of my magento website is not caching but I have no idea to do that. Anyone knows how to find out which block/part of the website is not caching? Can I find it out through analyzing /var/cache folder ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Search block in xml file and find the attribute "cacheable" = true or fale
2. by PHP, load a block in layout and call method isCacheable()